# Do I keep my PHP simple auth session secure enough?

Tags: php, cookies, session-management, bcrypt, sha

I'm experimenting with security, cryptography and web applications. My aim is to create simple login system that is **realy secure enough**. I'd like to share my approach to keep authenticated session with you to get some comments.

My approach:

When te user signs in (I use BCrypt and password_verify):

```
session_regenerate_id(TRUE);
$_SESSION['session_token'] = mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
$app->setCookie('auth', hash_hmac("sha256", $_SESSION['session_token'].$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], SESSION_SECRET));
$app->redirect($app->urlFor('index'));
```

All the cookies are encrypted with MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_192 in CBC mode (Slim framework takes care of it).

Then, at every request I perform those checks:

```
    $token = $app->getCookie('auth');
    if(!$token
        || !isset($_SESSION['session_token'])
        || hash_hmac("sha256", $_SESSION['session_token'].$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], SESSION_SECRET) !== $token
    ) {
         // user not logged in
    }
```

`SESSION_SECRET` is my defined random const string.

And here is my logout function:

```
$app->deleteCookie('auth');
session_destroy();
session_unset();
session_start();
session_regenerate_id(TRUE);
```

Is it secure enough in the matter of keeping user signed in?

Comment: Slim has a [built-in session cookie store](http://docs.slimframework.com/#Cookie-Session-Store). Please use that rather than hand-rolling your own.

Comment: Although I highly recommend setting the `secure` and `httponly` flags to `true`, while their documentation inexplicably demonstrates the opposite.

Comment: If your user remains "logged" in, and goes to another IP address (wifi <-> 3g, or renewed his external IP, ....), or when he upgrades the browser, you'll end his session?

Comment: What would in your case be "really secure enough"? If you have nothing to protect and would merely like to "keep user signed in" then I guess it's good enough. Please clarify.